# PostgreSQL - Min Max Entries

Tags: postgresql

I have a view called Students that displays their name, school, phone number and date started and it looks as below

```
select * from Students;
```

and the results are as below

```
Name        |    School    |    Phone    |    Date_Started

Student A    Electrical Eng   0424477876      1/02/2008
Student B    Software Eng     0425432598      1/02/2008
Student C    Mathematics      0487639487      2/02/2012
Student D    Photovoltaic     0425588596      4/06/2012
Student G    Commerce         0425588692      6/08/2014
```

Now I need to create a view that finds out the students that started first and also the students that started last based on date started and should produce the following output

```
Started    |    Name    |    School    |    Date_Started
first        Student A   Electrical Eng     1/02/2008
first        Student B   Software Eng       1/02/2008
last         Student G   Commerce           6/08/2014
```

So this requires a new view to use the already existing view to achieve this.

I am new to postgreSQL and have tried case statements which don't seem to be working, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a window function to calculate that in a single statement:

```
select *
from (
  SELECT case 
           when date_started = min(date_started) over () then 'first' 
           when date_started = max(date_started) over () then 'last'
         end as Started, 
         Name, School, Date_Started
  FROM Students 
) s 
where started in ('first', 'last')
order by date_started;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [UNION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-union.html) to combine results from two queries.

```
SELECT 'first' Started, Name, School, Date_Started
FROM Students WHERE Date_Started = (SELECT MIN(Date_Started) FROM Students)
UNION
SELECT 'last' Started, Name, School, Date_Started
FROM Students WHERE Date_Started = (SELECT MAX(Date_Started) FROM Students)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked!! However I am wondering, for the minimum there were 2 entries, shouldn't PostgreSQL find the first minimum entry and just output that? because when you type select min(date_started) from Students, it just outputs 1 row.

Comment: @uniaus Yes `SELECT MIN(...)` just returns one row, but there are more than one row having the same value as the minimum. The outer query will select both entries.

Answer (score 0):

hi You can try this ans

```
select 'First' as 'Started',* from student where Date_Started =(select min(Date_Started) from student)
union
select 'Last' as 'Started',* from student where Date_Started =(select max(Date_Started) from student)
```

Comment: Hi Rushabh, thanks for this. It worked, i am wondering why for the minimum it returned both the minimum entries and not just the first one because when you type select min(date_started) from students, it returns the first one it finds.

Comment: Yes you are correct it returns only one value. but we have two entries with the same values so we have put that value in where clause which return all values which we have mention as min or max